# Python array program not giving correct output

Tags: python, arrays

I am using below code for adding an element in array but it is giving me below error while running it

```
cars = ["Ford", "Volvo", "BMW"] 
cars.append("Honda") 
cars[4] = "BMWq";
for x in cars:
  print(x) 

Output error
```

List assignment index out of range

Not able to understand reason of this error

Comment: As the error says, the index is out of range. `cars` doesn't have an element at index 4. You need to push to it, you can't just assign to arbitrary indices.

Comment: What are you expecting to get? Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: You can't assign to a non-existent list index; you need to use `list.append` to add a new element.

Comment: Also, there are no arrays here. It's all lists.

Comment: @Carcigenicate why it works fine when i do cars[3] = "BMWq"; then what is the issue with cars[4] As i am appending an item just above it

Comment: @user1234 Because `cars` has an element at index 3 that can be overwritten. There isn't an element at index 4 though to overwrite.

Comment: That is an atrocious dupe. Surely a better one exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't extend a Python list by assigning values to an element that doesn't exist. This

```
cars.append("Honda")
```

is the correct way to assign a *new* element 3. To assign element 4 that does not yet exist, call `cars.append()` again.